# Mapping Multiple Struct Instances To One Address

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design

How can I map multiple struct instances to one user without overriding the previous instance? I want to retrieve both instances through one mapping query. Should I use a multi-dimensional array here or a nested mapping?

As an example. If I have the below two structs. The problem is that the cookie mapping will only retrieve the latest cookie hidden by the cookieContributor but I want to retrieve all the cookies contributed by this particular address? How should my mapping look to achieve this?

```
contract HiddenCookies {

    struct Cookie {
        string cookieID
        string name,
        string color,
        string flavor,
        uint amount
    }

    struct CookieJar {
        address[] cookieContributors; 
        mapping(address => Cookie[]) cookies;
        Cookie[] cookieJarContent;
        uint cookiesHiddenForLater;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like `mapping(address => YourStruct[])` should do the job, though it's hard to say for sure, when relying on your extremely too-broad description!

Comment: I edited the question to hopefully shed more light on my problem @goodvibration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

goodvibration's answer is correct, but just to expand a bit:

When you use `mapping(address => Cookie[]) cookie;` what you are getting is a multidimensional array, in a way. There's a "list" of addresses (the mapping) and each address has a list of Cookies (the array `Cookies[]`).

Then, when a user sends a Cookie to the CookieJar, instead of setting the Cookie with

`cookie[msg.sender] = myCookie;`

You'd do something like

`cookie[msg.sender].push(myCookie);`

As a suggestion, I'd change the name of the mapping from `cookie` to `cookies` (plural) because I believe it's more readable that way.